# Вызов активности из потока

Tags: android, java

Доброе время суток.

Я только начинаю программировать на андроиде, так что сильно не ругайтесь.

У меня в главной активности создается поток, который вычитывает данные, которые приходят по UART (код нажатой кнопки). И в зависимости от данных мне необходимо либо выполнять какие-то действия в главной активности, либо вызвать другую активность. В новой активности тоже нужно считывать данные через UART и в зависимости от полученных данных выполнять различные действия с новой активностью (или вызывать еще одну активность).

Вот вопрос: как это правильно делается?

**Обновление**

Работа с UART вынесена в отдельный класс. Объект SerialPort создается в главной активности следующим образом:

```
mSerialPort = mApplication.getSerialPort();
mOutputStream = mSerialPort.getOutputStream();
mInputStream = mSerialPort.getInputStream();
```

Сам поток у меня имеет следующий вид:

```
public class ReadUART_Thread extends Thread {
  int size;
  byte[] mBufferRX = new byte[myBufferSize+16];
  while (!isInterrupted()) {
    size = mInputStream.read(mBufferRX);  -- это собственно считывание UART
    formationData(mBufferRX, size);   -- обработка полученных данных
  }
}
```

После этого в главной активности в `onCreate()` я создаю и запускаю поток:

```
mReadUART_Thread = new ReadUART_Thread();
mReadUART_Thread.start();
```

В зависимости от полученных данных мне необходимо создать еще одну активность. И в ней тоже надо отслеживать данные полеченные из UART

Comment: У вас поток привязан к Activity должен быть.

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо за потраченное время на ответы. Но можно еще вопрос? А если создать Service, в нем создать Thread в котором вычитывать буфер UART то как подключится к этому процессу? И как можно организовать передачу данных из процесса а активную Activity?(ведь о получении данных знает только поток процесса) И еще, как можно из процесса, после приема данных, передать их в Activity которая на данный момент активна?(т.е. процесс стартовал в главной Activity, а реакция на пришедшие данные должна быть следующей запущенной Activity)

Comment: @selya, задавайте новый вопрос вопросом, а не комментарием к предыдущему.

Comment: @selya работа с сервисом тянет на отдельный вопрос уже )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `Activity` определить хендлер:

```
public Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      //здесь что-нибудь делаем
   }
};
```

из потока вызываете:

```
myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

**UPD:** пишу прям тут, проверить код сейчас нет возможности.

Создаём интерфейс:

```
public interface HandlerInterface{
   public Handler getHandler();
}
```

В ваших активностях:

```
public class MyActivity ... implements HandlerInterface{

   @Override
   public Handler getHandler(){
      return myHandler;
   }
}
```

Когда вы инициализируете поток, передаёте туда ссылку на Activity, а в конструкторе что-то вроде:

```
HandlerInterface handler;
...
public MyClass(HandlerInterface handler){
   this.handler = handler;
}
```

Затем, вызывайте хендлер так:

```
this.handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

В вашем случае:

```
public class ReadUART_Thread extends Thread {
   HandlerInterface handler;
   public ReadUART_Thread(HandlerInterface handler){
        this.handler = handler;
   }
   ...
}
```

А дальше  `this.handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);` вызывайте, где надо.

Comment: А как в потоке можно определить, какая активность сейчас активна? Ну и если я правильно понял, то для каждой активности будет свой хендлер? И будет ли виден хендлер второй активности, если поток был создан в первой. (

Comment: @selya у вас в любом случае активно единовременно может быть лишь 1 активность. Когда вы создаёте поток, то передаёте туда ссылку на активность.

Comment: @selya сложно сказать, я с UART не работал никогда и не знаю, что и как вы там инициализируете)

Comment: @selya в каждой активности создать какой-нить хендлер и реализовать интерфейс, который будет возвращать этот хэндлер. А в конструктор потока вы передаёте ссылка на этот интерфейс. Когда надо в потоке обращаетесь к этой ссылке, вызываете метод по получению хэндлера и sendEmptyMessage(0) ему вызываете

Comment: @selya особо сильно в этом плане от других языков оно не отличается. Если вы напишите, как выглядит конструктор у вашего класса по работе с UART (и можно ли от него унаследоваться), то могу написать.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @Suvitruf То, что Вы написали, я понял до "Когда вы инициализируете поток, передаёте туда ссылку на Activity". Я же инициализирую поток только один раз, в главной активности, и все. Дальше он работает в бесконечном цикле